# Fortify Translator severe error: specified path, file name, or both are too long

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, fortify

While translating a **C#** solution with **fortify 18.10**, on the ***Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017***, i get the following error on the **sca.log**:

> [2019-11-26 11:10:21.078 Thread-16 **SEVERE** 1103] Translator execution
>   failed.  Please consult the Troubleshooting section of the User
>   Manual.  Translator returned status -2147024690:
>
> DOTNET-DEBUG: Unhandled exception: **The specified path, file name, or
>   both are too long**. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260
>   characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

The command issued is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_18.10\bin\sourceanalyzer.exe" -b test-build-id-48df2a2423671960b5f911260f922c3a0e50807f devenv MySolution.sln /REBUILD debug
```

On the log, before the `SEVERE` message, only files way under 248 characters are handled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `build-id` get concatenated to other file names, without any log of the file being outputted.

It's important to shorten the build identifier.

With the name `test-48df2a2` source analyzer will complete the execution.